# Как подключить модуль блога в yii2 advanced?

Tags: yii2

модуль установился через composer. в backend\config\main добавлено

```html
'blog' => [
            'class' => 'medeyacom\blog\Blog',
```

во view\left

```html
 ['label' => 'Блог', 'icon' => 'pencil', 'url' => ['/blog']],
```

fronted\config\main

```html
 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => /*require(__DIR__ . '/../../frontend/config/routes.php'),*/
             [
             'blog/<url>'=>'blog/one',
             'blog'=>'blog/index',
             'blog/delete-image'=>'blog/delete-image'
            ],
        ],
```

в backend [image: скрин]

во fronted  [image: скрин2]

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: блог не подключается и не отображается нигде. во fronted если на брать http://yii2.com/blog Class 'common\components\behaviors\StatusBehavior' not found'
cкрины и код models\Blog.php добавлю в вопрос. в backend http://admin.yii2.com/blog - page not found 404

Answer (score 1):

В репозитории модуля этого файла просто нет. На packagist в зависимостях, кроме фреймворка тоже ничего. Варианта у вас три.

1. Обратиться к автору модуля, написав об этой проблеме в **issues** на
   **github**
2. Написать **StatusBehavior** к этому модулю самому, предполагаю что он необходим для
   изменения поля **status_id**
3. Написать модуль для блога самостоятельно

Comment: так я сам этот модуль и написал, но дело в том, что в одном проекте 
 с подключённым блогом все работает, а в этом нет. но я настолько запутался в нём, что удалил уже все. у меня ещё мало опыта в Yii2. и вот как снова подключить блог- пока не знаю, какой алгоритм должен быть.

Comment: В первом у вас работает, потому что StatusBehavior в common лежит. Если вы хотите использовать его в других проектах, то перенесите этот behavior в модуль тоже